# How to eliminate repeated elements and palindromes in a set of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have:

```
a = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 0)]
b = [(4, 5), (2, 0)]
c = [(2, 6), (5,3)]
lists = [a, b, c]
```

so I would need a function to generate

```
list = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 0), (4, 5),(2, 6), (5,3) ]
```

referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) question I am already able to delete repeated elements but I cant figure out how to solve the palindromes

Comment: Are your elements always length-two tuples?

Comment: yes they are an always in the (a, b) format

Comment: What is a palindrome in this context?  A tuple with two equal elements?

Comment: Yes for example (1, 2) and (2, 1) are palindromes

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) Currently the question asks how to remove duplicates and reversed duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this. I used `frozenset` because it allows to be hashed and like `set` it doesn't care about the order - so takes care of your palindromes and duplicates:

```
from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen
from itertools import chain

a = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 0)]
b = [(4, 5), (2, 0)]
c = [(2, 6), (5,3)]
lists = [a, b, c]
```

A sample run:

```
>>> list(unique_everseen(chain.from_iterable(lists), key=frozenset))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 0), (4, 5), (2, 6), (5, 3)]
```

The recipe for `unique_everseen` can also be borrowed from the [itertools python documentation page](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) if you don't want an external module.

---

And if you have items with more than 2 elements you could use this as `unique_everseen`-function. (slightly changed from the recipe):

```
def remove_duplicates_and_reversed(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:     
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)       # takes care of duplicates
            seen.add(item[::-1]) # takes care of reversed duplicates
            yield item

>>> list(remove_duplicates_and_reversed(chain.from_iterable(lists)))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 0), (4, 5), (2, 6), (5, 3)]
```

Comment: This approach will only work with pairs, no? `(0, 1, 3)` and `(1, 0, 3)` are not palindromes, but they will be the same set.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The [OP said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992343/in-python-how-to-eliminate-repited-elements-and-palindromes-in-a-set-of-lists/41992410#comment71161827_41992343) that it's only about 2-tuples

Comment: @Prune check the original solution before the edits.

Comment: It's still there (first solution), I only added a more general alternative as well (second solution). :)